# the folder and the file i link cannot be found

Tags: html

Hello I put all my plugins and CSS in a folder and I separated all my code in a different folder and my system cannot read the path I link. that's why my data In tables is not showing.

here's the error I found in console

[image]

heres my file looks like
[image]

pages folder
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JswUJ.png)
here's my code

```
<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- DataTables JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatablesplugins/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/datatablesresponsive/dataTables.responsive.js"></script>

    <!-- Morris Charts JavaScript -->
<script src="vendor/raphael/raphael.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/morrisjs/morris.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Try /vendor .....

Comment: i've tried it sir but its not working

Comment: try ~/vendor or ../../vendor

Comment: same error message sir @ammad

Comment: HELP PLEASE! my data is not showing in the table because of my plugins. what can I do about it?

Comment: please try to add a schematic directory like ```folders tree diagram``` to show your paths. sometimes it happens due to workplace directory

Answer (score 0):

this is your direct link
http://ssi-tms.com.ph/pages/

vendor folder is outside the pages folder that's why error is occurred

Tip-1: move vendor folder in pages folder
Tip-2:Change your direct link from http://ssi-tms.com.ph/pages/ to http://ssi-tms.com.ph/

Your file is accessible when I removed pages follow tip I mentioned
http://ssi-tms.com.ph/vendor/datatables/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js

Comment: tip-1 recommended move vendor folder into pages folder

Comment: i follow the tip-1 sir but i have the same error

Comment: did you upload your publish to server???

show me a picture of pages folder

Comment: sir i cant upload the the snap capture pages folder here

Comment: sir @ammad i upload it on my question.